# Punctuation to show possession

Tags: punctuation

Which is correct?
The British Broadcasting Company's (BBC's) policy ...
The British Broadcasting Company's (BBC) policy ...
The British Broadcasting Company (BBC)'s policy ...

Answer (score 4):

> British Broadcasting Company's (BBC's)

**No,** I have never seen anyone do something like this. It's confusing.

> British Broadcasting Company (BBC)'s

**No,** again, I have never seen this used. Imagine if there was a line break between "Company" and "(BBC's)," that would also be confusing.

Therefore, "The **British Broadcasting Company's (BBC)** policy ..." is the only correct answer. Indeed, [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28BBC%29%2C%20%28BBC%29%27s&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28BBC%29%3B%2Cc0) couldn't find *any* references to **(BBC)'s** and very few for **(BBC's)**, and looking through the result for **(BBC's)** shows mostly spurious matches anyway.

Secondly, when I was a copy editor for my university paper, I always would have used "British Broadcasting Company's (BBC)."

However, if I was *writing*, I would have tried to recast the sentence to avoid such a problem anyway. Final thought, do you even need to expand BBC? Depending on your audience, it might be acceptable to use "BBC" on first reference (check your style guide), like NASA, FBI, or CIA is in the U.S.

Comment: I did find examples of the ideas I gave but with different companies (not BBC). I must admit that I preferred recasting the sentence to avoid the problem! Thanks.

Comment: But did you find examples in edited publications, books, newspapers, etc? Or just on crap like BuzzFeed? Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if it helped you!

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't remember where they were - probably on Linguee!